# val_accuracy not changing but it is very high

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, scikit-learn, keras

My model's validation accuracy doesn't change and I have been trying to fix it for a while, but now the accuracy is very high. I'm not sure if that means my model is good because it has high accuracy or should I be concerned about the fact that the accuracy doesn't change.
In addition, every time I run the code each fold has the same accuracy.
code:

```
def model_and_print(x, y, Epochs, Batch_Size, loss, opt, class_weight, callback):
    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    seed = 7
    np.random.seed(seed)

    # define 10-fold cross validation test harness
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

    # Define per-fold score containers
    acc_per_fold = []
    loss_per_fold = []

    # K-fold Cross Validation model evaluation
    fold_no = 1
    for train, test in kfold.split(x, y):
        print(x[train])
        lda = LDA(n_components=1)
        x[train] = lda.fit_transform(x[train], y[train])
        x[test] = lda.transform(x[test])
        print("------------------------------------")
        print(x[train])


        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dropout(0, input_shape=(len(x[0]),)))
        model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.4))
        model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

        # compile model
        model.compile(optimizer=opt,
                      loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy']
                      )

        # Generate a print
        print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')

        # fit model

        history = model.fit(x[train], y[train], validation_data=(x[test], y[test]), epochs=Epochs,
                            batch_size=Batch_Size, verbose=1, class_weight=class_weight)
        # , callbacks=[callback]



        # Generate generalization metrics
        scores = model.evaluate(x[test], y[test], verbose=1)
        print(
            f'Score for fold {fold_no}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1] * 100}%')
        acc_per_fold.append(scores[1] * 100)
        loss_per_fold.append(scores[0])

        # Increase fold number
        fold_no = fold_no + 1

    # == Provide average scores ==
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Score per fold')
    for i in range(0, len(acc_per_fold)):
        print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print(f'> Fold {i + 1} - Loss: {loss_per_fold[i]} - Accuracy: {acc_per_fold[i]}%')
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Average scores for all folds:')
    print(f'> Accuracy: {np.mean(acc_per_fold)} (+- {np.std(acc_per_fold)})')
    print(f'> Loss: {np.mean(loss_per_fold)}')
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')

    # summarize history for accuracy
    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    # summarize history for loss
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()


def main():
    data = ["data.pkl", "data_list.pkl", "data_mean.pkl"]
    df = pd.read_pickle(data[2])

    x, y = data_frame_to_feature_and_target_arrays(df)

    # hyper meters
    Epochs = 2000
    Batch_Size = 64
    learning_rate = 0.3
    optimizer = optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    loss = "binary_crossentropy"
    class_weight = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y), y)
    class_weight = dict(enumerate(class_weight))

    es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)

    model_and_print(x, y, Epochs, Batch_Size, loss, optimizer, class_weight, es_callback)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

part of out put of last fold and summary of all folds:

```
64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4697 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 42us/step - loss: 0.4644 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2812 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1943/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4318 - accuracy: 0.7969
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 68us/step - loss: 0.4475 - accuracy: 0.7945 - val_loss: 0.2811 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1944/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5224 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 68us/step - loss: 0.5245 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2812 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1945/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5170 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4984 - accuracy: 0.7945 - val_loss: 0.2814 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1946/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5684 - accuracy: 0.7188
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5538 - accuracy: 0.7260 - val_loss: 0.2813 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1947/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4427 - accuracy: 0.7969
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.4470 - accuracy: 0.7945 - val_loss: 0.2812 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1948/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5000 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 68us/step - loss: 0.4960 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2810 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1949/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4940 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4959 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2809 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1950/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4776 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 37us/step - loss: 0.4751 - accuracy: 0.8082 - val_loss: 0.2810 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1951/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4514 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4978 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2818 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1952/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5187 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.5224 - accuracy: 0.7260 - val_loss: 0.2818 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1953/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4045 - accuracy: 0.8438
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4094 - accuracy: 0.8356 - val_loss: 0.2816 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1954/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5283 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4958 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2816 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1955/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5244 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5246 - accuracy: 0.7260 - val_loss: 0.2819 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1956/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4830 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4899 - accuracy: 0.7945 - val_loss: 0.2820 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1957/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5231 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.5053 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2819 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1958/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4301 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4422 - accuracy: 0.8082 - val_loss: 0.2818 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1959/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4817 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4824 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2818 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1960/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4598 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4839 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2819 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1961/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4983 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4958 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2818 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1962/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4872 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4844 - accuracy: 0.7671 - val_loss: 0.2819 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1963/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4871 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4859 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2818 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1964/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4188 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.4230 - accuracy: 0.8219 - val_loss: 0.2815 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1965/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5283 - accuracy: 0.7188
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5309 - accuracy: 0.7123 - val_loss: 0.2814 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1966/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5033 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.4809 - accuracy: 0.7671 - val_loss: 0.2813 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1967/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4611 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.4626 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2814 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1968/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5145 - accuracy: 0.7031
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5024 - accuracy: 0.7260 - val_loss: 0.2813 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1969/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5231 - accuracy: 0.7031
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5099 - accuracy: 0.7260 - val_loss: 0.2812 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1970/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4966 - accuracy: 0.7656
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.5019 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2811 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1971/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4728 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4818 - accuracy: 0.7671 - val_loss: 0.2810 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1972/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4607 - accuracy: 0.7656
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4753 - accuracy: 0.7671 - val_loss: 0.2809 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1973/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5350 - accuracy: 0.7031
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.5241 - accuracy: 0.7123 - val_loss: 0.2809 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1974/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4490 - accuracy: 0.7969
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4625 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2809 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1975/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5022 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4917 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2807 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1976/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5628 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5517 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2807 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1977/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4203 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.4283 - accuracy: 0.8082 - val_loss: 0.2805 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1978/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4796 - accuracy: 0.7656
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.4890 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2806 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1979/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4471 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.5046 - accuracy: 0.7671 - val_loss: 0.2811 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1980/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4724 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.4743 - accuracy: 0.7671 - val_loss: 0.2810 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1981/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5025 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.4842 - accuracy: 0.8082 - val_loss: 0.2811 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1982/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5298 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.5178 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2809 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1983/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4816 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.4959 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2806 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1984/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4713 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 109us/step - loss: 0.4899 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2804 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1985/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3938 - accuracy: 0.8281
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.4105 - accuracy: 0.8219 - val_loss: 0.2802 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1986/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5256 - accuracy: 0.7188
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.5156 - accuracy: 0.7260 - val_loss: 0.2801 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1987/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5261 - accuracy: 0.7188
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 95us/step - loss: 0.5187 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2800 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1988/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5315 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.5097 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2800 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1989/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5448 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5441 - accuracy: 0.7397 - val_loss: 0.2801 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1990/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4220 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 68us/step - loss: 0.4212 - accuracy: 0.8219 - val_loss: 0.2800 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1991/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4956 - accuracy: 0.7344
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 69us/step - loss: 0.5134 - accuracy: 0.7260 - val_loss: 0.2799 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1992/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4724 - accuracy: 0.7812
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 68us/step - loss: 0.4784 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2803 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1993/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4280 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 83us/step - loss: 0.4244 - accuracy: 0.8219 - val_loss: 0.2806 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1994/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4116 - accuracy: 0.8281
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 68us/step - loss: 0.4122 - accuracy: 0.8356 - val_loss: 0.2805 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1995/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4958 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.4934 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2804 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1996/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5281 - accuracy: 0.7500
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 0.5280 - accuracy: 0.7534 - val_loss: 0.2804 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1997/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4441 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 82us/step - loss: 0.4460 - accuracy: 0.8082 - val_loss: 0.2803 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1998/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4106 - accuracy: 0.8125
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.4056 - accuracy: 0.8356 - val_loss: 0.2800 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 1999/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4229 - accuracy: 0.8281
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 41us/step - loss: 0.4157 - accuracy: 0.8493 - val_loss: 0.2795 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2000/2000

64/73 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4924 - accuracy: 0.7969
73/73 [==============================] - 0s 68us/step - loss: 0.4920 - accuracy: 0.7808 - val_loss: 0.2797 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

8/8 [==============================] - 0s 123us/step
Score for fold 10: loss of 0.27967995405197144; accuracy of 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Score per fold
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 1 - Loss: 0.9029330015182495 - Accuracy: 66.66666865348816%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 2 - Loss: 0.251650869846344 - Accuracy: 87.5%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 3 - Loss: 0.15162397921085358 - Accuracy: 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 4 - Loss: 0.12148290127515793 - Accuracy: 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 5 - Loss: 0.1457768827676773 - Accuracy: 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 6 - Loss: 0.17563441395759583 - Accuracy: 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 7 - Loss: 0.1939687728881836 - Accuracy: 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 8 - Loss: 0.2388959378004074 - Accuracy: 87.5%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 9 - Loss: 0.1327996551990509 - Accuracy: 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Fold 10 - Loss: 0.27967995405197144 - Accuracy: 100.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Average scores for all folds:
> Accuracy: 94.16666686534882 (+- 10.408329472389672)
> Loss: 0.25944463685154917
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Some problems are easy. I don't think this is necessarily a problem with the model per se. If I were to find potential places for an error, it would be with how the data were obtained and processed. Perhaps the is some kind of non-independence that means the source data is a really, really good estimator of the test data. Yesterday's stock price is a good predictor of today's, etc.

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for getting back, does that mean I can trust the results and assume that I have a good model?

Comment: If you’re worried that it’s too good to be true, then I’d start looking for problems upstream of the neural network: data processing and data collection. In particular, I don't know what LDA does, but I wonder if that has a large influence over your results. On the other hand, if you're sure the problem is the neural network itself, then I'd experiment with reducing the number of units to discover what level of network capacity becomes perfect.

Comment: @Sycorax The LDA is used as a dimensionality reduction technique, when I don't use it  the validation accuracy does change in most folds, but the accuracy drops. I think that LDA does include some kind of pre-processing but I'm not sure why that would make the validation accuracy stay the same, and is that even a problem?

Comment: @Sycorax ok I found out that the LDA is making each value in a row the same value, so that's why the model's validation accuracy is not changing. I'm still not sure if that means that I can trust the results.

Comment: There are lots of statistical methods called LDA. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Sycorax linear discriminant analysis

Comment: Linear discriminant analysis is, on its own, a classification method. So following LDA with a neural network is basically stacking two classifiers together. I wonder how much of a boost the NN is adding in addition to LDA. Anyway, since LDA is just a way to find a linear combination to separate classes, it's less general than a neural network. So, just tune the network instead of relying on LDA to do the heavy lifting.